# Split number from 1 to N into more than one section

Tags: javascript

I need to split a number to number of sections

I want number of sections, between each consecutive numbers in each section the number of the sections

For example

If the given number is `20` and the number of sections is `3`
then need to split numbers 1 to 20 into three sections.

So the result will be

section 1 = `[1,4,7,10,13,16,19]` // between any

section 2 = `[2,5,8,11,14,17,20]`

section 3 = `[3,6,9,12,15,18]`

I'm using javascript to do this.... any idea

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: How exactly does the number 30 factor into your calculations below?

Comment: please add the wanted results of the given examples.

Comment: in my case it is a length of a json array
but it doesn't matter how it comes i need the logic

Comment: May be working number is `20`?

Comment: the wanted result is the value of the three sections below `section 1, section 2, section 3`

Comment: yes it is i wrote 30 by mistake sorry

Comment: This seems like a programming exercise. What have you tried so far?

Comment: what if the given number is `34` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two nested `for` loops and count the sections and the value to max.

```js
function getSection(sections, max) {
    var value, result = [], i;
    for (i = 1; i <= sections; i++) {
        result.push([]);
        for (value = i; value <= max; value += sections) {
            result[i - 1].push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getSection(3, 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
function get_s(s_cnt, w_num) { 
    var a = new Array(s_cnt), b = Math.ceil(w_num/s_cnt), c = w_num; 
    for (var i=0; i<s_cnt; i++) {
        var b_ = (b < c) ? b : c; c -= b;
        a[i] = new Array(b_); 
        for (var j=0; j<b_; j++) {
            a[i][j] = j*s_cnt + i + 1;
        }
    } 
    return a; 
}
var s = get_s(3,20);
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) console.log("section "+(i+1)+": "+s[i].join(", "));
```